# How to apply CIFilter to UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, cifilter

According to **`Apple docs,`** filters property of `CALayer` is not supported in `iOS`. As i used one of the apps which are applying `CIFilter` to `UIView` i.e. Splice, Video Editor Videoshow FX for Funimate and artisto. That's means we can apply `CIFilter` to `UIView`.

I have used `SCRecorder` library and try to get this task done by `SCPlayer` and `SCFilterImageView`. But i am facing black screen issue when video is playing after apply `CIFilter`. So kindly help me to complete this task so that i can apply `CIFilter` to `UIView` and also can change the filter by clicking on a UIButton.

Comment: I don't know about this , But the effect that you want you can achieve it by using GPUImage Framework also. That is much easier to use also.

Comment: Show some code. A typical error would be that you forgot to set `myView.wantsLayer = true`

Comment: GPUImage Framework is applying filters only on live video not recorded video. I want to apply apply filters on already recorded video and also want to get preview of applied filter at runtime before export.

Comment: @Rameez have you find any solution for this? I have same problem please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: @YogendraPatel Yes my problem was solved but not with applying filter to UIView. Because we can't apply CIFilter to UIView.

Comment: @Rameez Ok, please give me your other solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The technically accurate answer is that a `CIFilter` requires a `CIImage`. You can turn a `UIView` into a `UIImage` and then convert that into a `CIImage`, but all CoreImage filters that use an image for input (there are some that generate a new image) use a `CIImage for input and output.

- Please note that the origin for a `CIImage` is bottom left, not top left. Basically the Y axis is flipped.
- If you use CoreImage filters dynamically, learn to use a `GLKView` to render in - it uses the GPU where a `UIImageView` uses the CPU.
- If you want to test out a filter, it's best to use an actual device. The simulator will give you *very* poor performance. I've seen a simple blur take nearly a minute where on a device it will be a fraction of a second!

Let's say you have a `UIView` that you wish to apply a [CIPhotoEffectMono](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPhotoEffectMono) to. The steps to do this would be:

- Convert the `UIView` into a `CIImage`.
- Apply the filter, getting a `CIImage` as output.
- Use a `CIContext` to create a `CGImage` and then convert that to a `UIImage`.

Here's a `UIView` extension that will convert the view *and* all it's subviews into a `UIImage`:

```
extension UIView {
    public func createImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
            CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height), true, 1)
        self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

Converting a `UIImage` into a `CIImage` is one line of code:

```
let ciInput =  CIImage(image: myView.createImage)
```

Here's a function that will apply the filter and return a `UIImage`:

```
func convertImageToBW(image:UIImage) -> UIImage {

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectMono")

    // convert UIImage to CIImage and set as input

    let ciInput = CIImage(image: image)
    filter?.setValue(ciInput, forKey: "inputImage")

    // get output CIImage, render as CGImage first to retain proper UIImage scale

    let ciOutput = filter?.outputImage
    let ciContext = CIContext()
    let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciOutput!, from: (ciOutput?.extent)!)

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
}
```

Comment: I tired your provided solution but i am getting only black screen. If i do try this solution on whole view then it is working because i have some visual controls in my screen i.e. buttons, top bar etc. But this solution is not working on a specific view i.e. my video player's view. My player view's background color is clear.

Comment: I must not understand the issue then. First, a black screen possibly means you are using a blank image as input. But my confusion probably is surrounding on that "specific" view you want. Is that some type of a video screen? If so, while I *did* answer your question (it was asking for a `UIView`), you are right, simply turning a `UIView` into a `CIImage` for applying a CIFilter won't work.

Comment: Yes it is a video player's view. I want to apply filters on video. 

I can apply filters to that video by using AVMutableVideoComposition's applyingCIFiltersWithHandler callback constructor. As you know this callback will take some time to produce filtered video. 

But i want to give preview of filter at runtime to user. Just like applications are already providing this feature i.e. Splice, Video Editor Videoshow FX for Funimate and artisto. I know these apps are not applying filters directly to videos. They are using any type of image, uiview or layer.

Comment: No, not *directly* to videos. Still, this isn't a simple `UIView` or static image. The best direction I could give you is this repo/blog - https://github.com/FlexMonkey/LiveCameraFiltering - it's in Swift 2, meaning you'll need to either use Xcode 8 to upgrade to Swift 3 or change the Swift Language Version in Xcode 9 and manually convert - but I think it'll help you. Good luck!

Comment: This library is dealing with live camera feed. But i checked his blog in detail. He also worked on recorded video and provided blog [link](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.nl/2016/04/loading-filtering-saving-videos-in-swift.html?showComment=1466655328057) . So this blog solved my problem as i expected. Thank you very much. Really appreciation from me.

Comment: He's a great resource. His (now free) iBook, *Core Image for Swift* is highly recommended if you wish to write your own CIFilters. It's written in Swift 2 but most of the code doesn't change - and the largest change he wrote a blog post on there.

Comment: Well that's great. But this book is not yet available in pakistan store.

Comment: Ow. Didn't know that. I checked the blog again, and here's a link for a "pay what you want" PDF: https://gumroad.com/l/CoreImageForSwift Here's the blog post - it has an embedded video: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2016/05/core-image-for-swift-version-13.html?q=core+image+for+swift

Comment: Thanks man. I got the this pdf. This will be surely helpful regarding Core Image related tasks.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Even though my answer isn't a correct one for your issue, I'll keep it posted for others down the road. (Unless you want me to delete it.)